# how to get unique id on each blogger post

Tags: jquery, blogger

i am trying to move the post image from the div element to another div with jquery "prependTo" [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n4jdxzbm/9/)

```
$('.post img').prependTo('.move');
```

because I use a class selector, then each image will be moved and piled on each element of the 'move' class

```
<div class='post-body' expr:id='"post-body-" + data:post.id'>
<div class='move'/>
<div class='post'>
    aaa aaa aaa
    <img src="image-1"/>
    bbb bbb bbb
</div>
</div>

<div class='post-body' expr:id='"post-body-" + data:post.id'>
<div class='move'/>
<div class='post'>
    ccc ccc ccc
    <img src="image-2"/>
    ddd ddd ddd
</div>
</div>

<div class='post-body' expr:id='"post-body-" + data:post.id'/>
<div class='move'/>
<div class='post'>
    eee eee eee
    <img src="image-3"/>
    fff fff fff
</div>
</div>
```

it seems that I should get a unique id of each post, or is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? how to generate a unique id?

Comment: Stay the image inside the same post-body? and do you want this on a click event?

Comment: yes, this will generate an example like this in the browser "post-body-3955r55122095409882". I want to get it automatically @e11i0t23

Comment: @JQuest no, actually i made a different look on the homepage with special condition tags. but in the item page, image will return to its original position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need post id, Try this

```js
$('.post-body').each(function () {
   $(this).find('.post img').prependTo($(this).find('.move'));
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='post-body' expr:id='"post-body-" + data:post.id'>
<div class='move'></div>
<div class='post'>
    aaa aaa aaa
    <img src="image-1"/>
    bbb bbb bbb
</div>
</div>

<div class='post-body' expr:id='"post-body-" + data:post.id'>
<div class='move'></div>
<div class='post'>
    ccc ccc ccc
    <img src="image-2"/>
    ddd ddd ddd
</div>
</div>

<div class='post-body' expr:id='"post-body-" + data:post.id'>
<div class='move'></div>
<div class='post'>
    eee eee eee
    <img src="image-3"/>
    fff fff fff
</div>
</div>
```